# Keep element position fixed to parent using transform on scroll

Tags: css, css-position, css-transforms

I understand it's possible to `position:fixed` a child element relative to it's parent using `transform`. When scrolling the document, is it possible to keep the fixed child's position relative to it's **parent**, rather than the document?

**Demo**
https://jsfiddle.net/ds0vbtbt/3/

**Update**: Above is a simiplied version of my problem. `position:absolute`: is not the solution I'm looking for.

**Update**:
Doesn't seem possible without JS once the initial transform is performed

Comment: have you tried to put parent to position relative?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón yea the parent is set to relative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah you can do that with position absolute, provided the containing element is set to relative. You don't need the transform property at all.

```
.test {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ds0vbtbt/1/

An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

**Update:** `position: fixed` is always going to relative to the view-port - so if you change the window size it will be updated, but when scrolling it wont be. That said, Elements with transforms act as a containing block for fixed position descendants, so position:fixed under something with a transform no longer has fixed behavior. They do work when applied to the same element; the element will be positioned as fixed, and then transformed.

Comment: thanks for your answer, updated the question. position fixed with transform will create a local coordinate and always place the fixed element relative to it's parent. However, on scrolling the document this position is not "updated". I wonder if this is possible without using `js´ – Stevanicus 1 min ago   edit

Comment: position: fixed is always going to relative to the viewport - so if you change the window size it will be updated, but when scrolling it wont be. That said, Elements with transforms act as a containing block for fixed position descendants, so position:fixed under something with a transform no longer has fixed behavior. They do work when applied to the same element; the element will be positioned as fixed, and then transformed.

Comment: yea, so the only way to update the position after the initial transform is going to be using `js` isn't it?

Comment: It will be yeah due to the way the fixed position behaves

Answer (score 0):

You are using **position:fixed** which fix the element with viewport.
Use **position:absolute** for child element to fix it with parent element.

Comment: thanks for your answer, updated the question. position fixed with transform will create a local coordinate and always place the fixed element relative to it's parent. However, on scrolling the document this position is not "updated". I wonder if this is possible without using `js´

Comment: yea sorry, came a bit late :)